# How to To Hide Answer section in standard Feed,Post and comment component used in salesforce community?

Tags: customer-community

We have used Feed, Post and Comment standard component on the community page.
Now, our requirement is we need to hide the Answer section which comes under when we post any FAQ.

Please find the below image for reference.

[image]

Already , tried by disabling Chatter setting options like:

1. Allow users to edit posts and comments
2. Allow users to compose rich text posts
3. Allow post pinning

But, did not achieve any output from these settings.
So, please let me know if there are any other settings we need to perform to hide the answer section from the Feed, Post and comment standard component I salesforce community.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard component, as in this case it's [Feed Post & Comments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_feed_item_detail.htm&type=0), and that the component itself does not provide any "property" to be able to modify the contents, then you cannot show/hide any particular section on that component itself. The way this component works is that it always includes the answer section, so you cannot remove it.

This is applicable for any standard component that you use, as it's abstracted and exposed by the platform to be used in as-is form unless there's an option to modify it using any of its properties/attributes.

For your use case, if at all you want to hide answers, you need to write a custom component, or a validation that Users cannot post answers. The prior approach is recommended here.